# insert SharePoint list column [created by] ,[modified by] insto sql table using C# CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to insert a custom SharePoint list into a sql table

This is the code . I am not able to insert [created By] into the sql table as it errors out ,

```
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp2010");
        Web web = context.Web;
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("EmployeeTasks");
        context.Load(list);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(list.Title + "\n");
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View/>";
        ListItemCollection allitems = list.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(allitems);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        DataSet EmpDataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da;

        cn.ConnectionString = "";
        cn.Open();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from EmployeeTasks", cn);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Fill(EmpDataSet, "EmployeeTasks");

        DataTable table = EmpDataSet.Tables[0];

        foreach (ListItem listitem in allitems)
        {
          //  Console.WriteLine(listitem["desc"].ToString());
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();


            row["EmployeeEmail"] = listitem["EmployeeEmail"].ToString();
          //  row["desc"] = listitem["desc"].ToString();
          ////  row["CreatedBy"] = listitem["Created By"].ToString();--error how to get column names with spaces in it
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            builder.GetInsertCommand();
        }
        da.Update(EmpDataSet, "EmployeeTasks");  

  //  conn.Close();
    Console.Read();
```

Comment: Sharepoint list's by default have "created by" , "Modified By" columns , I want to push that into a SQL table

Comment: @Robert is the question clear , if it is clear can you take the hold off

Comment: Yes I can, but I will not right now since your question still does not contain a question at all. It does not contain an explanation of your problem or trials so far either (it is just a code snippet copy-pasted in withou any explanation)

Comment: Can you please try to clarify your problem so I can reopen it? And please do that in the question body and not in the title or in comments

Comment: @Robert What part is not clear  , I want to insert a custom SharePoint List which by default has [modified by] and [createdy by]  into a sql table ..and that is the code I am trying to execute in my Visual studio 2013 environment .. if you are the one who is making this decision I dont want to be part of this community so let me know either ways that way I can stop wasting my time

Comment: This is nothing personal so please do not take it that way. You have now clarified your question, and therefore it has been reopened. Please read this section from the community help on how to ask good questions for further guidance: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also this section about different close reasons is worthy a read-through http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 3):

You should use the internal names of the columns when you retrieve them, so this row

```
row["CreatedBy"] = listitem["Created By"].ToString();
```

would be

```
row["CreatedBy"] = listitem["Author"].ToString(); // Author is internal name of Created By
```

which will give you a result like

```
1;#Anders And
```

So depending on what you need to do with the value later on you might need to process that value a bit more